# Angular 7 Unable to include a custom typescript definition file

Tags: angular, typescript, types, angular7

I created a custom typescript definition file (brat.d.ts)

```
export declare class head {
   ready(callback: () => any);
}

export declare class Util {
   static embed(divId: string, collData: any, docData: any, webFontsURLs: Array<string>);
}
```

I am importing the above definition file in Angular 7 components like this

```
import {head, Util} from "../../brat/brat";
```

When I do ng serve, I get following error

'ERROR in ./src/app/folder-mgmt/list-documents/list-documents.component.ts
***Module not found***: Error: Can't resolve '../../brat/brat' in '\src\app\folder-mgmt\list-documents'`

Can anyone please suggest what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I did following

I removed export from my custom typescript definition file (brat.d.ts) file and changed it to

```
declare class head {
   static ready(callback: () => any);
}
declare class Util {
   static embed(divId: string, collData: any, docData: any, webFontsURLs: Array<string>);
}
```

Angular project created using Angular CLI have tsconfig.json file in the root folder of project.

I added the path of folder containing custom definition file inside "typeRoots" property of "compilerOptions" present in tsconfig.json.

[image]

In the Angular component I removed import statements for importing custom typescript definition file ("brat.d.ts" in my case)

Comment: doesn't work for me in Angular 8 :(
I created myfile.d.ts, added it to TypeRoots, but still component can't find the declaration of the class (

Comment: can u share your declaration file (myfile.d.ts). In typeRoots, the path should start from src folder

Comment: Thanks for advice to move to src folder. It was outside :(. Now it works, but I have no idea how to move the declarations to a module. Anyway I'm happy without a compilation error

Answer (score 10):

You add declarations in a .d.ts file, and they become globally available in your project. But you'll need to tweak the `tsconfig.json` firstly, by adding the following:

```
"files": [
  "additional.d.ts"
]
```

Now create a `./addition.d.ts` file (relative to your TypeScript project root) and add your typings there. Do not `export` symbols, only declare the types.

```
declare class head {
   ready(callback: () => any);
}

declare class Util {
   static embed(divId: string, collData: any, docData: any, webFontsURLs: Array<string>);
}
```

You'll now have them available globally.

If you don't want them available globally but you're instead adding typings for a module which is missing them, declare them inside a module.

```
declare 'module-name' {
  // ...
}
```

Now TypeScript will recognize those when you do `import { ... } from 'module-name'`.

Comment: I included my class definition inside a declare 'module-name' and added "files":["./src/app/brat/brat.d.ts"] inside root tsconfig.json file of Angular 7 project.

But now I get following error

Error:<complete-path>\metis-ui\src\main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Error: <complete-path>\metis-ui\src\polyfills.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Comment: using angular9 nguniversal (ssr) adding my external file to `tsconfig.server.ts` worked for me. `"files": [ "server.ts","additional.ts"]` when I added it to `tsconfig.json` ssr build threw error.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem, took some research and some **SO** links, in your case make sure to import correctly 
i.e. import {head, Util} from "../../brat/brat"; --> **import {head, Util} from "../../brat/brat.d";**
as when importing modules you dont add the file extension and your module is brat.d.ts, that said.

In my case have a conflict when a file(module) e.g item.ts which contains the class i export, Item,

```
export class Item {
  public reference: string;
  public name: string;
   constructor( name: string, reference: string) {
     this.reference = reference;
     this.name = name;
   }
   get getReference(): string {
     return this.reference;
   }
   get getName(): string {
     return this.name;
   }
   set setName(newName: string) {
      this.name = newName;
   }
 }
```

on import with `import { Item } from './models/item';` in the component which makes use of the class, and saving (Ctrl+s) in the component had `ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,20): error TS2306: File 'D:/PROJET/Personal Resoruces/Angular2/DuckFowl/src/app/Models/item.ts' is not a module.`.
I changed the file(module) name to **item.models.ts** keeping the class unchanged and everything was ok. Keeping the module name different from that of the exported class, function, interface etc, can help, but you are free to use any name.

Make a **Ctrl + s** of the file containing the exported element and that of the Component, to refresh Angular CLI.

Resolved my issue.

[Screen shot of project component and model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjZx8.png)

My Config

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.6
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.6
@angular/cli                      8.3.6
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.6
@schematics/angular               8.3.6
@schematics/update                0.803.6
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Love&Lead ;-)